# tidying up code: check multiple values and return null if any of them found

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I have multiple scripts to check for different values in a radio button, then return null in a dropdown if it's found, but they're redundant. I want to combine them into one, so it searches for multiple values, and if it finds any of them in the radio button, returns null in the dropdown. Here are two. I just haven't been able to successfully combine them:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="item_meta[101]"]').change(
function () {
var valCheck = this.value === '4 Categories - $90';
$('select[name="item_meta[106]"]').val(function () {
return valCheck ? 'null' : this.value;
});
});

$('input[type="radio"][name="item_meta[101]"]').change(
function () {
var valCheck = this.value === '3 Categories - $60';
$('select[name="item_meta[106]"]').val(function () {
return valCheck ? 'null' : this.value;
});
});
```

It should be pretty simple but I'm hitting a wall.

Comment: var valCheck = (this.value === '3 Categories - $60' || this.value === '4 Categories - $90'); ?

Comment: That works too skishore. And very simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="item_meta[101]"]').change(function () {
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    var arr = [ "4 Categories - $90", "3 Categories - $60" ]
    if ($.inArray(thisVal, arr))
    {
        //do whatever needs to happen
    }
}
```

Comment: That most definitely works. Took me a minute to figure out parsing, but works like a charm. Thanks very much!